# How to display logged in user's profile picture in android app using ProfilePictureView from Facebook SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I want to display the profile picture of a logged in user in my android app.How to do that using the method ProfilePictureView in Facebook SDK?Please help...

Comment: I think facebook SDK is providing the picture tag in response, just get it and display it.

Comment: @Nevaeh There's a bit involved in that. Have you at least done anything at all? I can't add post a whole solution here

Comment: I did that.But the picture need to be displayed in a circular  shape.For that i can use the library CircularImageView.But then i cant use the  ProfilePictureView widget.So i want to download the image and display it in my imageview.could u tell me how to download the profile picture of the logged in user.I am parsing the profile information json and have the id of user.How to download and display his profile picture ?

Comment: @Nevaeh you will need to do this job manually by making a request and parsing the response(s) by yourself. I'll add some more info in an answer rather than a comment

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the user's photo using the `CircularImageView` library. You can still make requests to the Facebook Graph API and parse the response by yourself. You can do this manually or using the Android SDK for Facebook by making a request to the following endpoint...

```
graph.facebook.com/v2.1/me/picture
```

of course, you can replace `me` by a specific user's id. You don't need to request any special permissions in the access token. The request about will render a json response similar to the one below...

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/v/t1.0-1/blahblahblah_n.jpg?oh=2xgdgfdhgdhdhg33ba58e021&oe=5dghgdh_gda__=1dgfhdfh88_b9gdhfghfghfghfghfgh408d6e7", 
    "is_silhouette": false
  }
}
```

this json response contains the following fields:

1. url: which is a url from where you can request the profile picture
2. is_silhouette: which determines whether the picture is the default facebook silhouette or not. If the user has not added a profile picture, then the facebook default silhouette will be returned in the url...see below

[image]

You can also use the Android SDK for Facebook, create a request object, pass in the current session object, execute the request asynchronously, for example...

```
new Request(
    _currentSession,
    "/me/picture",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            //parse the response
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

For more information you can read the [documentation on their site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/picture) and even use the Graph API Explorer for testing purposes

Comment: Great !!! thanks for help...I referred to tons of tutorials.I am getting image but when i used CircularImageView,it gives exception.What to do ?java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fbsample/com.example.fbsample.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class CircularImageView